Oracle APEX 19.2 Calendar region - Selected date value post to another page item
The request is the same of this : (Oracle APEX 19.2 Calendar Create Link - Send selected date to linked page)
My Apex version is 19.2.
I have a calendar region on a page, based on a table with ranged dates (e.g. 11/07/2024 - 28/11/2024; 5/8/2024 - 15/08/2024... etc.). I've to send the selected date value to another page item (no matter then the selected date is present in table's range..).

I've just tried to make a Dynamic Action by choosing the Event : Date Selected [calendar]:

Dynamic action event
with &APEX$NEW_START_DATE. in an alert display null value

I've tried to use the tutorial, and in Calendar's region Attributes -> Create Link -> Set Value (of destination item) and &APEX$NEW_START_DATE. in Value field

Can sameone help me?
Thanks in advance.
Alessandro
